# Json array sorting according to column field

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, sorting, next.js

I have a component in Next.js, and I want to sort them according to which columns selected from dropdown.

In here I got an error like this and I can't handle it

```
sortedData.sort((a, b) =>
        e.value === "ascending"
          ? a[selectedColumn] - b[selectedColumn]
          : b[selectedColumn] - a[selectedColumn]
      );
```

**Error:** *Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ id: number; name: string; height: number; }'.ts(7053)*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import classes from "./SortingBar.module.css";
import { Dropdown } from "primereact/dropdown";

type Props = {};

type Order = "ascending" | "descending";

const SortingBar = (props: Props) => {
  const [selectedOrder, setSelectedOrder] = useState<Order | null>(null);
  const [selectedColumn, setSelectedColumn] = useState<any>(null);

  const [data, setData] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "A", height: 1.67 },
    { id: 3, name: "C", height: 1.65 },
    { id: 2, name: "B", height: 1.68 },
    { id: 4, name: "D", height: 1.7 },
    { id: 6, name: "F", height: 1.69 },
    { id: 5, name: "E", height: 1.66 },
  ]);

  const orderChangeHandler = (e: { value: Order }) => {
    if (selectedColumn) {
      setSelectedOrder(e.value);

      const sortedData = [...data];
      sortedData.sort((a, b) =>
        e.value === "ascending"
          ? a[selectedColumn] - b[selectedColumn]
          : b[selectedColumn] - a[selectedColumn]
      );

      console.log(sortedData);

      setData(sortedData);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.sidebarContent}>
        <div className={classes.description}>
          <h5 className=" text-gray-800 mt-3 mb-3">Sorting</h5>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div className="col-12">
            <h6>Select field </h6>
            <Dropdown
              className="w-full"
              placeholder="Select column"
              options={[
                { label: "id", value: "Id" },
                { label: "name", value: "Name" },
                { label: "height", value: "Height" },
              ]}
              onChange={(e) => setSelectedColumn(e.value)}
              value={selectedColumn}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-12">
            <h6>Select order </h6>
            <Dropdown
              className="w-full"
              placeholder="Select order"
              options={[
                { label: "Ascending", value: "ascending" },
                { label: "Descending", value: "descending" },
              ]}
              onChange={orderChangeHandler}
              value={selectedOrder}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-12">
            {data.map((item) => (
              <div className="flex flex-wrap align-items-center">
                <div className="col-4">{item.id}</div>
                <div className="col-4">{item.name}</div>
                <div className="col-4">{item.height}</div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SortingBar;
```

Comment: What if you made the type of selectedColumn to string so you can index the object's? `const [selectedColumn, setSelectedColumn] = useState<string>('');` Also, you would have to change either the keys of your data, or use the lowercase value of the dropdown to select which key to sort by because `'Height' != 'height'` etc.

Comment: I updated as you said and it's sorting but I still keep getting the same error